# can you help me please

Tags: updates

every time I want to update software this message pops up "he repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cpug-devs/ppa/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.". How to fix this?

Comment: Please specify the title with your problem.

Comment: Remove this PPA.

Comment: Sry. The correct link is https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from a piece of software called `cpu-g` at some point you have installed this software and it does not have a package for Eoan. To fix this it is likely the release file is stored in

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Finding the file with the cpug-devs url and deleting it will resolve the issue.

It is also possible that someone manually added this line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. If this is the case editing the file something similar to

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and removing the line with cpug-devs in (save the file and exit) will also solve the problem

run
`sudo apt update` once the file or line is removed and you should be error free